# ASP.Net MVC3 Razor Data Insertion is not working when using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Hello in my project my data is not insert in the database when  using EF.Its an ASP.Net MVC3 Razor Project.
So i tried to debug the program ,but its not working .When we click the save button it simply reload the page .

Here am using EF Code to save data.

**View Code**

```
<p>Welcome To @ViewBag.User</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset class="default-fieldset">
<div></div>
 <legend>Employee Registration Form</legend>
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
<div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>


 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Middle Name</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class ="form-control" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Age</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date Of Birth</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control",@id="dp1" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "tinymce-simple span12",@row="25",@cols="45",@width="30%" })</div>


 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Position</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Position, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Department</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Department, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>


 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date of joining</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfJoining, new { @class = "form-control",@id="dp2" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Qualification</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EducationalQuali, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Experience :If any</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Experience, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Others</label>

 <div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Others, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
 <div class="Button-Div-Sepa"></div>
 <div class="Button-Div">
 @*<input type="button" class="" />*@
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> @Html.ActionLink("Save","EmployeeRegistration","Employee")</button>
 <button class="btn btn-success">Clear</button>
 <button class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
}
</div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmployeeRegistration(Employee emp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.EmpData.Add(emp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**Model**

```
[Table("tbl_Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age{get;set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
        public string EducationalQuali { get; set; }
        public string Experience { get; set; }
        public string Others { get; set; }
```

**Database Context**

```
public class ElixirERPContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Menus> DataMenu { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> EmpData { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.EmpData.AddObject(emp);
db.SaveChanges();
db.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Updated Answer as problem described in comments:

Its means your `db and entity model db is different, first update entity model` then try to save

Comment: @Nidheesh Can you debug `Modelstate is valid`

Comment: It not getting into the if Loop.That means Modelstate is not valid.isn't?

Comment: Its getting the error message that The model backing the 'ElixirERPContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: Its means you db and entity model db is different, first update entity model then try to save

Comment: @Nidheesh if that's the problem, I recommend you to follow visual basic advice, to use Code First Migrations.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I have updated my Entity Model and now its working Fine.So can u please post it as an answer.Then I can close this question as accepted.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal...OKay :) .